# Converting object to json control fields name upper case first letter

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AccountSyncResponse 
{
        private String Result;
        private String Value;

        public AccountSyncResponse() {}            

        public String getResult() {return Result;}
        public void setResult(String Result) {this.Result = Result;}
        public String getValue() {return Value;}
        public void setValue(String Value) {this.Value = Value;}        
}
```

Rest Web Service:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public AccountSyncResponse excute(AccountSyncRequest ASReq) 
    {        
       AccountSyncResponse ASRes = new AccountSyncResponse();
       return ASRes;    
    }
```

The result is `{"result":"Create","value":"123456"}`

I need it the first letter of fields name to be in upper case `{"Result":"Create","Value":"123456"}`

How can I control fields name in the resulting json string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) as show below:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AccountSyncResponse  {

    @XmlElement(name = "Result")
    private String result;

    @XmlElement(name = "Value")
    private String value;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Alternatively you can annotate the getters with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) (then the [`@XmlAccessorType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) annotation is not required).

---

Alternatively to JAXB annotation, you might want to consider Jackson. It's a popular JSON parser for Java that [can be used with Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson). Then you can use [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) instead (however Jackson can also work with JAXB annotations).

With Jackson, depending on your needs, you can use a [`PropertyNamingStrategy`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) such as [`PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.html).

Comment: If OP wants to capitalize *all* field names, it might be better to modify the default name mapping behaviour of Jersey instead of annotating all fields.

Comment: @jarnbjo I've added more details to my answer to cover that ;)

Comment: @Cassio Mazzochi Molin When adding `@XmlElement` the data in the result json string is duplicated with upper case and without.
`{"Result":"Create","Value":"123456","result":"Create","value":"123456"}`

Comment: @asabd You can follow **one** of the the following approaches: **1)** Annotate the getters instead of the fields. **2)** Annotate the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

Comment: @Cassio Mazzochi Molin Annotating the getters instead of the fields did the job. Many thanks.